# How to resolve Array to String conversion error Laravel

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

I'm new to laravel and i encountered an array to string conversion error while trying to send tags select form data to sync with my blogs table.

Below is blade snippet that retrieves tags from the database

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="tag" class="control-label">Tags</label>
   {!! Form::select('tag[]', $tags, old('tag'), ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'id' => 'add-tag' ]) !!}   
 </div>
```

The BlogsController

```
$blog_data = request()->validate([
            'tag.*' => 'required'
    ]);

 blogs = Blog::create( $blog_data );  
     $blogs->tags()->sync((array)request()->input('tag'));
```

when i perform a dd on request()->tag

```
  array:2 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
]
```

Comment: I think this issue relates to https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/issues/464 which I encountered some time ago. The issue is that LaravelCollective/html does not seem to work well with array inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, i was able to remove this line of code and it worked

```
tag.*' => 'required'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use like this

```
$blogs = Blog::create( $blog_data );
```

If insert then use like this

```
$blogs->tags()->attach($request->tag);
```

If update then use like this

```
$blogs->tags()->sync($request->tag);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that already and it doesn't work

Comment: for the insert operation

Comment: @Alkari then you have to use `attach`

Comment: $blogs->tags()->attach( request()->tag);  this doesn't work

Comment: @Alkari It's a many to many relation right?? If yes then it should be work. I use this code minimum 5 to 7 project at all.

Comment: Kindly refer to my code on github https://github.com/Alvinkariuki/Blog-Post.git

Comment: Please say your view and controller which has problem

Comment: BlogController function( store ) and the  view ~ (blogs.create)